# Paginate options in checkbox of a form field

Tags: paging

I have a custom form with a field of type checkboxes,options for which I am getting from another function which takes an array as input, do some theming on options value and return options back to form,

Here is how my another function looks like

```
function mymodule_twitter_accounts_as_options($twitter_accounts) {
  $options = array();
  if (is_array($twitter_accounts)) {
    foreach ($twitter_accounts as $twitter_account) {
      $key = $twitter_account->twitter_id;
      $options[$key] = theme('image', array('path' => $twitter_account->profile_image_url)) . mymodule_twitter_account_basic_info_block1($twitter_account) . mymodule_twitter_account_basic_info_block2($twitter_account);
    }
  } return $options;
}
```

The array `$twitter_accounts` is coming from a database query, which is extending drupal pagination but I do not think the extended pagination will be helpful here as I need to show a global pagination for all the options rendered in the form later.

**Edit:**

The reason I am using a form is only because of the reason that once user checks checkboxes and submit the form, I am doing some operations using checkboxes key values, If there is an alternate to use of custom form that will be good too.

Comment: huh! when I am passing pager in url, I am seeing pager is wroking, I can conclude only after theming the query pager.I think the way I asked was not clear,else i would have got the solution before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be no one will land up here,still adding the answer and foolish doubts I had

The pagination done for query to get options works! .

The reason I was in doubt before was because of using the query results as option of checkbox field, the time I added themed the pager while rendering the form, I got the pager which worked out of the box!

How I figured out if pagination working with the query was by adding `?page=1` in the url manually which changed the checkboxes , it ensured me I just have to theme the global pager :) .